# Mysql - Get average of time diff between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables :

```
customer
  id
  name
  created_at
```

and :

```
action
  id
  customer_id
  type
  created_at
```

I want to have the average time difference between `customer.created_at` and `action.created_at`, where `action.type = "call0"` and action is the first entry (action may have many `type = "call0"`)

For now, I have this query :

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(action.created_at, customer.created_at)) / 60) AS diff
    FROM action
     WHERE action.type = "call0"
    JOIN customer ON action.customer_id = customer.id
    GROUP BY customer.id
    ORDER BY action.created_at ASC
```

Dunno why, this query returns me several rows - each for action entry.

How can I return the whole average calculation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the total result  then don't group by for   customer.id

```
  SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(action.created_at, customer.created_at)) / 60) AS diff
    FROM action
    JOIN customer ON action.customer_id = customer.id
    WHERE action.type = "call0"
```

otherwise  if you want the avg for each customer.id the  try show also the corresponding customer.id

```
SELECT customer.id, AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(action.created_at, customer.created_at)) /60) AS diff
  FROM action
 JOIN customer ON action.customer_id = customer.id
  WHERE action.type = "call0"
  GROUP BY customer.id
  ORDER BY action.created_at ASC
```